# Pass an 8 byte long to a server using netcat?

Tags: netcat

I've written a server that expects a long from a client.  I'd like to test the server without writing a client.  Can I use netcat to pass a long to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use Perl for generating binary data:

```
perl -e "print(pack('H*', '0123456789abcdef'))" | netcat ...
```

Reading the `perldoc -f pack` documentation takes some time, but after this you can generate pretty much any data. I've mostly used the `H*` for now, it also has options for encoding numbers in 32-bit format, probably also 64-bit format.

Yours would probably be the `pack('q<', 0x0123456789abcdef)` or `'q>'`.